# Kendo Autocomplete must select Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo AutoComplete which populated when we type something in it.Now I want to validate this AutoComplete when user dont select the Option from Populated fields.
e.g If I have a list of Countries and when i type a first 3 char then autocomplte pops up.Now User must select the any field from pop ups.I mean i want to force the user to select the Countries.My code so far goes as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
  .Name("Account")
  .DataTextField("AccountName")
  .Filter("contains")
  .MinLength(3)
  .Template("#=data.AccountName#")
  .Events(events => events.Select("AccountSelect").Change("ChangeEntity"))
   .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 240px;" })
   .DataSource(source =>
           {
              source.Read(read =>
               {
                 read.Action("GetTransaction123", "Cashbox");
                    })
    .ServerFiltering(true);
           })
   )
```

I want to write some code on change event of this Auto Complete

```
function ChangeEntity(e)
    {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#transaction").validate({
                success: "valid",
                submitHandler: function () { alert("Submitted!") }
            })
        });

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to make sure the AutoCompleteField has a selected value when a form is submitted??

Comment: Yes..I want the user must select the value from the AutoComplete

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Select and Change events to test if the user has selected or typed a valid option. If text that is entered is not in the list, this will blank it out.

```
      @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
              .Name("Account")
              .DataTextField("AccountName")
              .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
              .Suggest(true)
              .HighlightFirst(true)
              .MinLength(3)
              .Events(e => e.Select("accountSelect"))
              .Events(e => e.Change("accountChange"))
              .DataSource(source => source
                .Read(read =>
                  read.Action("GetTransaction123", "Cashbox")
                )
                .ServerFiltering(true)
              )
      )    

<script>
  var accountIsValid = false;  

  // This was a valid account! Set the accountIsValid flag.
  function accountSelect(e) {
    accountIsValid = true;
  }

  // Clear the account field if the choice was not valid
  function accountChange(e) {
    if (!accountIsValid) {
      this.value('');
    }
    // Reset the accountIsValid flag for next run
    accountIsValid = false;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to give validation on AutoComplete while submitting form

If this is a scenario then you may use form validation, some thing like below

```
<div id="yourForm">
     @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete().Name("Account")......
     <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="Account"></span>
 </div>


<script>
    $("#yourForm").kendoValidator({
        rules: {
          customRule1: function(input) {
              if (input.is("[name=Account]")) {
                return input.val() === "";
              }
              return true;
            }
          },
        messages: {
            customRule1: "Account field is required"
        }
    });
</script>
```